# Apache Mahout K-means clustering implementation

Tags: java, apache, mahout, k-means

I have tried KmeansDriver's run() function but I did not give true parameters. Trustly, I did not understand implementation of this function. Is there a clear example about that which takes a matrix, dataset or file and gives clustered data?

I am trying to cluster a sparse matrix with using K-means algorithm. I will use Apache mahout but I did not find any example about how can it be implement with Java. Is there any tutorial or function javadoc about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look to the examples from book "Mahout in Action". For example, in chapter 7 there is a [minimal example](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch07/SimpleKMeansClustering.java) - for Mahout 0.5. Or you can look to the [same example for Mahout 0.7](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/mahout-0.7/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch07/SimpleKMeansClustering.java).

Comment: Hi, I used your code and it does not work for me [example Mahout 0.7](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/mahout-0.7/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch07/SimpleKMeansClustering.java). It gives me few IOException `DEBUG Configuration - java.io.IOException: config()` and finally there is an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-sadeckia\mapred\staging\myname-207333769\.staging to 0700`. Have you already met this issue?

Comment: it could be the problem with Hadoop on Windows - I don't have such setup to check what's wrong...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried to install Cygwin and I added it to `Path` but still this same error appears. I will try to launch it on UNIX.

Comment: Hi, finally I successfully used this piece of code. Now, I have got another question, how to make it work with apache mahout version 0.9?

Comment: this is a good question - there are plenty of changes between 0.7 & 0.9 - I've started to make them, but still haven't finished (and can't say when this will happen)

Comment: see the same code for version 0.9 : http://develop.nydi.ch/2014/04/02/mahout-clustering-example/